# How to find Weyl/temporal gauge fixing condition?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, maxwell-equations, gauge-invariance, gauge

Transformations that leave the field invariant:

$$\vec{A}' = \vec{A} + \nabla f$$
$$\phi' = \phi -\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$$

I would like to solve for the weyl gauge, aka a gauge that leaves

$$\phi' = 0$$

Solving for f:

$$0 = \phi -\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$$

$$  \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \phi$$

$$f = \int \phi dt$$
From here, if I solved the potentials in a specific gauge, I could easily perform a gauge transformation using the value of $\phi$ to find the corresponding potentials in the weyl gauge with ease.

However what about instead solving for the gauge fixing condition, and then using this condition to directly solve maxwells equations?

Taking the divergence of $\vec{A}$ transformation

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{A}' = \nabla \cdot\vec{A} + \nabla^2 f$$

Substituting our new definition of f

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{A}' = \nabla \cdot\vec{A} + \nabla^2 [\int \phi dt]$$

So when I substitute this into maxwells equations, I have the variables $\vec{A},\vec{A'},V ,V'$

What am I  missing as surely you cannot solve in this form.

**Edit 1 : I think this is correct but I think that I need to substitute it in. Given this gauge is correct, I can obviously just set $\phi = 0$ but I want to prove it.**

I perform a gauge transformation.

The potential formulation is:

$$\nabla^2 \phi' + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \nabla \cdot \vec{A}' = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

Substitute my definition of $\nabla \cdot \vec{A}'$

$$\nabla^2 \phi' + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} [\nabla \cdot\vec{A} + \nabla^2 \int \phi dt] = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

$$\nabla^2 \phi' + \frac{\partial \nabla \cdot \vec{A}}{\partial t}  + \nabla^2 \phi = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

Swapping the time derivative, and Factoring, we have

$$\nabla^2 \phi' + \nabla \cdot [\frac{\partial  \vec{A}}{\partial t}  + \nabla \phi] = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

We know that the old potentials give us the same E field! The inside of the brackets is just $-\vec{E}$

$$\nabla^2 \phi' - \nabla \cdot \vec{E} = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

From Gauss law:

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho }{\epsilon_{0}}$$

Meaning this mess reduces to poissons equation

$$\nabla^2 \phi' = 0$$

This is getting close to showing $\phi= 0$, but now we need to also show that aswell as $\phi$ satisfying poissons equation, it must also independantly satisfy the gauge condition.

How can I do this,  to show the only possible one is zero [even though I know I can use the definition of f to do so.]

Edit 2:

Not going to show the full math here, however, but I have shown that the old potentials also vanish when solving for A, but depends upon $\rho$ and $\vec{J}$ as expected!

$$\nabla^2 \vec{A}' - \mu_{0}\epsilon_{0}\frac{\partial^2 \vec{A}' }{\partial t^2} - \nabla[-\int \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}dt + \mu_0 \epsilon_{0}\frac{\partial \phi'}{\partial t}] = -\mu_0 \vec{J}$$

When we prove that phi is zero using our gauge fixing condition, we have $\vec{A}$ which is determined by both charge and current density!

Which would be:

$$\nabla^2 \vec{A}' - \mu_{0}\epsilon_{0}\frac{\partial^2 \vec{A}' }{\partial t^2} = - \nabla\int \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}dt  -\mu_0 \vec{J}$$

Someone do the math to see if I've made any mistakes!

Comment: I think I've got it,  substituting this gauge condition with manipulation leaves jt independant of the old potentials, I think.

Comment: I think the most sensible solution is to just use the definition of f, to say phi is zero with zero calculation from poissons equation.  But is there another way directly using the poissons equation?

Comment: I'm starting to think my gauge fixing condition is incomplete. If $\phi'$ is also some scalar function, such that $\int \nabla^2 \phi' dt = 0$ then it would have the same gauge fixing condition! Which explains why the eq reduces to poissons equation! I think I NEED to use the definition of f in order to solve this system of equations!